# Динамическая генерация регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать регулярное выражение, которое будет проверять на соответствие строку вида `"страна(переданная или любая)/город(переданный или любой)/улица(переданная или любая)"`

генерирую регулярное выражение:

```
let generatePattern = (filerOptions = {}) => {
    const options = {
        country: `[\\s\\S]`,
        city: `[\\s\\S]`,
        street: `[\\s\\S]`,
        ...filerOptions,
    };

    return pattern = new RegExp(`${options.country}\/${options.city}\/${options.street}`);
}


let reg = generatePattern({}); // /[\s\S]/[\s\S]/[\s\S]/
reg.test('dd/dd/dd'); // false
```

При этом если повторить тест с двумя составляющими, то все проходит:

```
    generatePattern = (filerOptions = {}) => {
        const options = {
            country: `[\\s\\S]`,
            city: `[\\s\\S]`,
            ...filerOptions,
        };

        return pattern = new RegExp(`${options.country}\/${options.city}`);
    }


    reg = generatePattern({}); // /[\s\S]/[\s\S]/
    reg.test('dd/dd'); // true
```

Как нужно составить регулярное выражение, чтобы проходил тест с тремя произвольными строками разделенными слэшами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что регулярка неправильная) `[\s\S]` — означает "один пробел ИЛИ один непробел". Тест `'dd/dd'` проходит, потому что есть такое совпадение — d`d/d`d. А с 3-м слешем уже не прокатывает) Чтобы совпал формат, нужно поставить плюсик, означающий "один или много раз". А "пробел ИЛИ непробел" можно заменить на "тупо всё" — `.` (на самом деле всё, кроме переноса строки)

```js
let generatePattern = (filerOptions = {}) => {
    const options = {
        country: `.+`,
        city: `.+`,
        street: `.+`,
        ...filerOptions,
    };
    let pattern = new RegExp(`${options.country}\\/${options.city}\\/${options.street}`);
    console.log( pattern );
    return pattern;
}

let reg = generatePattern({});
console.log( reg.test('dd/dd/dd') );
```

https://regex101.com/ — Удобная штука для регулярных выражений.